# SharePoint 2013 custom list infopath form loss of fuctionaility in people picker field

Tags: infopath, custom-list, people-picker

just wondering if there is a fix for the loss of functionality with the people picker field once you customize the default info-path form that comes with a sharepoint list.
If you see the default infopath form image i included below, once you start typing in the box, suggestions pop up below for the user to select but once you customize your infopath form this functionality is lost.
In the customized infopath form  picture shown below. All i did was change the background shading of the form to yellow but have lost the functionality of  default infopath. now when i start typing on the customized infopath form no suggestions are displayed to the user. This forces the user to search by clicking the people icon. Is there a way to restore this functionality to customized infopath form ?

[image: Default infopath form]

[image: Customized infopath form]

Comment: Have you found a solution for that issue?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think InfoPath has the type ahead people picker as it has the classic people picker. I sometimes provide help text below the InfoPath people picker that says "Use Email Address or open address book to search."